# About NOTSET in python logging

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

As the [logger.setLevel](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel) doc says:

> When a logger is created, the level is set to NOTSET (which causes all messages to be processed when the logger is the root logger, or delegation to the parent when the logger is a non-root logger). Note that the root logger is created with level WARNING.

so I think if I create a root logger, with level NOTSET, the debug and info log will display.

The code use basicConfig to set root logger's level to NOTSET is right:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.NOTSET)
log = logging.getLogger()

log.debug('debug')
log.info('info')
log.warning('warning')
log.error('error')
log.critical('critical')
```

and output is:

```
DEBUG:root:debug
INFO:root:info
WARNING:root:warning
ERROR:root:error
CRITICAL:root:critical
```

But if I create a root logger, and add handler with NOTSET level to it, such as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import logging

log = logging.getLogger()
hd = logging.StreamHandler()
hd.setLevel(logging.NOTSET)
log.addHandler(hd)

log.debug('debug')
log.info('info')
log.warning('warning')
log.error('error')
log.critical('critical')
```

the output is:

```
warning
error
critical
```

but I think it will also output the debug and info message.

Comment: What is missing in this test is: log.log(logging.NOTSET, 'notset') which does not seem to log anything to anywhere in spite of what the docs imply. log.handlers is None here. However explicitly adding a handler like your below solution also does not solve the problem of log level zero specifically.

Comment: @DevPlayer you are right, look at this problem now, I think to set root logger with 'logging.DEBUG' is enough and better; `logging.NOTSET` is not an effective level, it's used for delegation.

Comment: This is very very weird, where in the docs is this behaviour documented? It's had me puzzled the WHOLE day.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OK, I misunderstand the `Logger's level` and `Handler's Level`, in the doc:

> The setLevel() method, just as in logger objects, specifies the lowest severity that will be dispatched to the appropriate destination. Why are there two setLevel() methods? The level set in the logger determines which severity of messages it will pass to its handlers. The level set in each handler determines which messages that handler will send on.

If I change code to this, will be ok:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import logging

log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.NOTSET) # Set Logger's level to NOTSET, default is WARNING
#print "Logger's Level: ", log.level
hd = logging.StreamHandler()
hd.setLevel(logging.NOTSET)
#print "Handler's Level: ", hd.level
log.addHandler(hd)

log.debug('debug')
log.info('info')
log.warning('warning')
log.error('error')
log.critical('critical')
```

Comment: you need to add more details to this for it to make sense by itself.

Answer (score 4):

I also thought this was confusing. I interpreted NOTSET as don't produce logs. But...

> The level and handlers entries are interpreted as for the root logger, except that if a non-root logger’s level is specified as NOTSET, the system consults loggers higher up the hierarchy to determine the effective level of the logger. [source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html?highlight=notset)

and

> The level is interpreted as for loggers, and NOTSET is taken to mean ‘log everything’. [source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html?highlight=notset)

This makes sense because NOTSET (0) which is below DEBUG (10)

Comment: I *think* this is the answer I (and OP) were looking for. "**if a non-root logger’s level is specified as `NOTSET`, the system consults loggers higher up the hierarchy**".

From my testing, this also applies to handlers. If the handler is set to `NOTSET`, it will inherit the logger's level. And the [default logger level is `WARNING`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html). 

To be safe, play around with different log level print statements to see what level is actually shown.

Thank you for answering!

Comment: it broke my brain too. glad i could help in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Let's explain by example that UNSET does NOT do anything when creating concrete instances of loggers (for some mysterious reason):

```
def logging_unset_level():
    """My sample logger explaining UNSET level

    Resources: 
    - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21494468/about-notset-in-python-logging
    - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jxmzY9soFXg&t=468s
    - https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/tree/master/Logging-Advanced
    """
    import logging

    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__) # loggers are created in hierarchy using dot notation, thus __name__ ensures no name collisions.
    print(f'DEFAULT VALUE: logger.level = {logger.level}')

    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename='my_log.log')
    log_format = "{asctime}:{levelname}:{lineno}:{name}:{message}" # see for logrecord attributes https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes
    formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt=log_format, style='{') 
    file_handler.setFormatter(fmt=formatter) 

    stdout_stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
    stdout_stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO) 
    log_format = "{name}:{levelname}:-> {message}" # see for logrecord attributes https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes
    formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt=log_format, style='{')
    stdout_stream_handler.setFormatter(fmt=formatter)

    logger.addHandler(hdlr=file_handler)
    logger.addHandler(hdlr=stdout_stream_handler)

    logger.log(logging.NOTSET, 'notset')
    logger.debug('debug')
    logger.info('info')
    logger.warning('warning')
    logger.error('error')
    logger.critical('critical')
```

the output to screen is:

```
DEFAULT VALUE: logger.level = 0
__main__:WARNING:-> warning
__main__:ERROR:-> error
__main__:CRITICAL:-> critical
```

the output to `stdout` is:

```
2020-04-15 17:00:38,384:WARNING:200:__main__:warning
2020-04-15 17:00:38,384:ERROR:201:__main__:error
2020-04-15 17:00:38,384:CRITICAL:202:__main__:critical
```

as expected from the question's body, when the logger is instantiated its setting is `UNSET`. If you are using the basic config for some reason it does work as the docs imply it should *everything from UNSET to higher get logged* BUT when instantiating loggers concretely this setting makes only error messages work for some reason (find me a reference!).

Ok, now if you run it again but increase the level of the top logger everything works as you would expect (except the unset):

```
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

The output of stdout (note the stdout handler has level INFO in my example for pedagogical reasons, different from the file handler, trying to show inheritance of the .level value from the top logger):

```
DEFAULT VALUE: logger.level = 10
__main__:INFO:-> info
__main__:WARNING:-> warning
__main__:ERROR:-> error
__main__:CRITICAL:-> critical
```

and the output of the logger file `my_log.log` (this one DOES output the debug statements! :D ):

```
2020-04-15 17:05:58,782:DEBUG:198:__main__:debug
2020-04-15 17:05:58,784:INFO:199:__main__:info
2020-04-15 17:05:58,784:WARNING:200:__main__:warning
2020-04-15 17:05:58,784:ERROR:201:__main__:error
2020-04-15 17:05:58,784:CRITICAL:202:__main__:critica
```

is as expected. It inherited the top level loggers level so it printed everything from DEBUG level upwards.